# Error When Editing Member Variable in Class

Tags: class, delphi, constructor, delphi-xe4

I'm trying to use a class in my program.

```
TStack = Class
Public
  constructor Create; Overload;
  Procedure Add(Frm:TForm);
  Procedure Remove();
  Procedure Do_Close;

 Private
  List  : Array[1..Max_Forms] of Rec;
  Count : Byte;
End;
```

Constructor:

```
constructor TStack.Create;
begin
  Self.Count := 0;
end;

Procedure TStack.Add(Frm:TForm);
begin
  Inc(Self.Count);
  List[Count].Form     := @Frm;
  List[Count].Width    := Frm.Width;
  List[Count].Height   := Frm.Height;
  List[Count].left     := Frm.Left;
  List[Count].Top      := Frm.Top;
end;
```

I can't change value of Count variable! It cause Run-Time error : Access violation....Write of address 000001E4

What's the problem?!

FOR MORE INFORMATION:

I'm trying to store a pointer to each form in a structure like this :

```
  Rec = Record
      Form      : ^TForm;
      Maximized : Boolean;
      Width,
      Height,
      left,
      Top       : Integer;
    End;
```

And then

```
Procedure TStack.Do_Close;
var
  i      : integer;
  MyForm : TForm;
begin
 i := .....some code here.......;
 MyForm := @List[i].Form;
 ShowMessage('I will close '+MyForm.Caption);
 MyForm.Close;
end;
```

AND call constructor like this to initialize 'Count':

```
Stack.Create;
```

Comment: Which line crashes, the one in the constructor or the one in Add?

Comment: Lots of problems. The one that is probably hurting you is that you did not create the object correctly. You did not show that code. Please do. Use Integer to count, not byte. Don't use static arrays. Use dynamic arrays or `TList<T>`. Index arrays from 0. Don't take the address of local variables.

Comment: yeah, `Stack.create` does not work but `stack=Tstack.create` solved some problems(Why?!)! Why I should not use static arrays?! What do you mean about "Don't take the address of local variables"! Thank you guys :)

Comment: OT: There is a ready made `TObjectStack` class which (from the code you've shown) you might implement for your task.

Comment: @TLama I'm thinking that `Rec` is a record, a value type, and so not suitable for `TObjectStack`. Also, `TObjectStack` is legacy now that we have generics.

Comment: @David, that's true, but I was thinking about direct storing of the `TForm` instances to the stack. About generics, we don't know the Delphi version, so hard to suggest...

Comment: @TLama My policy is that if the user won't tell us the Delphi version, then assume it is modern. It doesn't really help the cause to restrict yourself to some ancient legacy lowest common denominator.

Comment: @David, the next time I will. Moreover, if I would write `TObjectStack<TForm>` it would self explain my thought.

Comment: @TLama Actually `TStack<TForm>` is what you would use. `TObjectStack<T>` is derived from `TStack<T>` and just adds the `T: class` constraint so that it can implement ownership of its members. But since the members are not owned by this container, `TStack<TForm>`  is clearer.

Comment: @Jessica Your edit improves things but you still have not included the key part of the question, the `Stack.Create` line. That would be good to add.

Comment: Thank you guys. Delphi version XE4

Comment: @David, no, I wouldn't :-) I would control the `OwnsObjects` property. But to be honest, some time ago I got mad when I found out the `Pop` method is a procedure. That time I used `TStack<T>`, but I'm preferring to use `TObject...<T>` collections to indicate that I'm working with objects regardless if I'm owning them or not.

Comment: @Jessica They you should use `TStack<T>` rather than creating an inferior stack class.

Comment: @TLama How can `TObjectStack<T>.Pop` be a function? What will it return? The object that it just destroyed?!! This is a well known issue with stacks and ownership. Discussed ad infinitum with regard to the C++ STL stack. Which, like any well designed stack, does not return anything in from its `Pop` method.

Comment: @David, uhm, a valid object ? I'm still talking about `OwnsObjects==False`. Yeah, it would be nonsense if the objects were owned.

Comment: @TLama Yes, but `OwnsObjects` is determined at run time, but the signature of the method is determined at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in comments you are attempting to create the object like this:

```
var
  Stack: TStack;
....
Stack.Create;
```

This is a classic mistake, and one that we've all made. You are calling a method on an uninitialized instance variable.

In order to instantiate a class you need to write this:

```
Stack := TStack.Create;
```

On top of that I have the following comments:

1. Use zero-based indexing for arrays. That's the convention everywhere in Delphi apart from anachronistic strings. And even that is changing in newer versions.
2. Don't use static arrays for a stack unless you have a good reason for doing so. You'll just run the risk of running out of space. Or allocating more memory than you need. Use a dynamic array.
3. Rather than a dynamic array, you could use `TList<T>`.
4. Even so, one wonders why you are making your own stack class when there is the perfectly good `TStack<T>`.
5. You store the address of a local variable in your stack. In `TStack.Add` you add `@Frm` into the container. As soon as `TStack.Add` returns, `@Frm` is meaningless. That's because `Frm` is a local variable whose life ends when the function that owns it returns. I think you want to take a copy of `Frm`.

Picking up item 5 in more detail, your record is declared like this:

```
Rec = Record
  Form      : ^TForm;
  Maximized : Boolean;
  Width,
  Height,
  left,
  Top       : Integer;
End;
```

It is a mistake to use `^TForm`. That is a pointer to a variable holding a pointer to an object. That's two levels of indirection, one too many. You must declare the `Form` field to be of type `TForm`. I suggest you revise the way Delphi object reference variables work. Delphi classes are what is known as reference types. A variable of type `TMyClass` where `TMyClass` is `class(...)` is already a pointer. The language automatically de-references the pointer when you use the `.` operator to access members.